# tuple index out of range when trying to fit model XgBoost

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I'm trying to train model xgboost on vectors of words.
When I do

```
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train["comment_preproc"], y_train["label"])
y_predict = model.predict(X_test["comment_preproc"])
```

I get the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-870161aebeee> in <module>()
      1 model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
----> 2 model.fit(X_train["comment_preproc"], y_train["label"])
      3 y_predict = model.predict(X_test["comment_preproc"])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    717             evals = ()
    718 
--> 719         self._features_count = X.shape[1]
    720 
    721         if sample_weight is not None:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I thought maybe X_train and y_train have different shape, but it's not the case
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tuples `(758079,)` and `(758079,)` consist only of one element.

Hence the error that you get:

```py
>>> t = (758079,)
>>> t[0]
758079
>>> t[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.to_frame()` to your `X_train["comment_preproc"]` Series:

```py
model.fit(X_train["comment_preproc"].to_frame(), y_train["label"])
```

or

```py
model.fit(X_train[["comment_preproc"]], y_train["label"])
```

It should work